# Singular error when putting a current source in series with a capacitor (ngspice)

Tags: capacitor, spice, ltspice

I am getting singular errors when I simulate a current source in series with a capacitor with the following .cir file:

```
* Spice netlister for gnetlist
C1 1 0 1
I1 1 0 1
.TRAN 100u 6m
```

(I understand a farad is huge, just to make the numbers easy. I have tried smaller capacitor values, but they have not helped.)

Based on my analysis,

```
I = C*(dV/dt)
```

Integrating, I expect

```
V = (I*t)/C.
```

So I would expect increasing voltage in the mV range over time when I plot v(1), but I get the following error at the below of this message. When I change the C1 into an R1, no error is observed at all. What is going on?

```
Doing analysis at TEMP = 27.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000

Warning: singular matrix:  check nodes 1 and 1

Note: Starting dynamic gmin stepping
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-03 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-04 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-05 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-06 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-07 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-08 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-09 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-10 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-11 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-12 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-12 Note: One successful gmin step
Warning: singular matrix:  check nodes 1 and 1

Warning: Dynamic gmin stepping failed
Note: Starting source stepping
Supplies reduced to   0.0000% Warning: singular matrix:  check nodes 1 and 1


Trying gmin =   1.0000E-02 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-03 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-04 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-05 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-06 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-07 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-08 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-09 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-10 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-11 Note: One successful gmin step
Trying gmin =   1.0000E-12 Note: One successful gmin step
Note: One successful source step
Supplies reduced to   0.1000% Warning: singular matrix:  check nodes 1 and 1

Supplies reduced to   0.0000% Warning: singular matrix:  check nodes 1 and 1

Warning: source stepping failed

Transient solution failed -

Last Node Voltages
------------------

Node                                   Last Voltage        Previous Iter
----                                   ------------        -------------
1                                                 0                    0


doAnalyses: iteration limit reached

run simulation(s) aborted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many circuit simulators attempt to find a DC operating point prior to executing a transient analysis. Basically, they replace inductors with short circuits and capacitors with open circuits and then solve the remaining circuit.

Your circuit has no stable DC point (open-circuit current source) and this process fails. Usually, there's a way to tell the simulator to skip the initialization step and specify starting conditions (e.g., Vcap = 0V) explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

SPICE simulations begin by finding a d.c. solution at t=0. At d.c. the current through a capacitor is zero so there is no solution for a non-zero current source in series with a capacitor. Change your constant current source to a source that has an initial value of 0.0A and then ramps up quickly to the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround would be to add a high ohm resistor in parallel to the capacitor, maybe 1M or 1G or so. Experiment a bit (same goes for @Joe Hass' answer) and see how much (or how little) the result changes.

Comment: There is a gotcha with Spice, if you enter 1m it will substitute it for 1 milli. If you want to enter 1 mega you have to enter 1meg.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .IC statement.

.IC Statement
This statement provides an alternative way to specify initial conditions of nodes (and thus over capacitors).

```
 .IC Vnode1 = value Vnode2 = value etc.
```

so .IC V(1) = 0

```
* Spice netlister for gnetlist
C1 1 0 100UF
I1 1 0 0.5
.IC V(1)=0
.OP
.TRAN 100u 6m
.print tran V(1,0) 
.end
```

And the result is

> run simulation(s) aborted
>                            * spice netlister for gnetlist
>
> ### Transient Analysis  Sat Feb 27 12:05:49  2016

### Index   time            v(1)

0   0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
1   6.000000e-07    -3.00000e-03
2   1.200000e-06    -6.00000e-03
3   2.400000e-06    -1.20000e-02
4   4.800000e-06    -2.40000e-02
5   9.600000e-06    -4.80000e-02
6   1.920000e-05    -9.60000e-02
7   3.840000e-05    -1.92000e-01
8   7.680000e-05    -3.84000e-01
9   1.536000e-04    -7.68000e-01
10  2.536000e-04    -1.26800e+00
11  3.536000e-04    -1.76800e+00
12  4.536000e-04    -2.26800e+00
13  5.536000e-04    -2.76800e+00
14  6.536000e-04    -3.26800e+00
15  7.536000e-04    -3.76800e+00
16  8.536000e-04    -4.26800e+00
17  9.536000e-04    -4.76800e+00
18  1.053600e-03    -5.26800e+00
19  1.153600e-03    -5.76800e+00
20  1.253600e-03    -6.26800e+00
21  1.353600e-03    -6.76800e+00
22  1.453600e-03    -7.26800e+00
23  1.553600e-03    -7.76800e+00
24  1.653600e-03    -8.26800e+00
25  1.753600e-03    -8.76800e+00
26  1.853600e-03    -9.26800e+00
27  1.953600e-03    -9.76800e+00
28  2.053600e-03    -1.02680e+01
29  2.153600e-03    -1.07680e+01
30  2.253600e-03    -1.12680e+01
31  2.353600e-03    -1.17680e+01
32  2.453600e-03    -1.22680e+01
33  2.553600e-03    -1.27680e+01
34  2.653600e-03    -1.32680e+01
35  2.753600e-03    -1.37680e+01
36  2.853600e-03    -1.42680e+01
37  2.953600e-03    -1.47680e+01
38  3.053600e-03    -1.52680e+01
39  3.153600e-03    -1.57680e+01
40  3.253600e-03    -1.62680e+01
41  3.353600e-03    -1.67680e+01
42  3.453600e-03    -1.72680e+01
43  3.553600e-03    -1.77680e+01
44  3.653600e-03    -1.82680e+01
45  3.753600e-03    -1.87680e+01
46  3.853600e-03    -1.92680e+01
47  3.953600e-03    -1.97680e+01
48  4.053600e-03    -2.02680e+01
49  4.153600e-03    -2.07680e+01
50  4.253600e-03    -2.12680e+01
51  4.353600e-03    -2.17680e+01
52  4.453600e-03    -2.22680e+01
53  4.553600e-03    -2.27680e+01
54  4.653600e-03    -2.32680e+01

### Index   time            v(1)

55  4.753600e-03    -2.37680e+01
56  4.853600e-03    -2.42680e+01
57  4.953600e-03    -2.47680e+01
58  5.053600e-03    -2.52680e+01
59  5.153600e-03    -2.57680e+01
60  5.253600e-03    -2.62680e+01
61  5.353600e-03    -2.67680e+01
62  5.453600e-03    -2.72680e+01
63  5.553600e-03    -2.77680e+01
64  5.653600e-03    -2.82680e+01
65  5.753600e-03    -2.87680e+01
66  5.853600e-03    -2.92680e+01
67  5.953600e-03    -2.97680e+01
68  6.000000e-03    -3.00000e+01

CPU time since last call: 0.024 seconds.

Total CPU time: 0.024 seconds.

Total DRAM available = 7925.503906 MB.
DRAM currently available = 4380.695312 MB.
Total ngspice program size = 14.254883 MB.
Resident set size = 2.011719 MB.
Shared ngspice pages = 1.771484 MB.
Text (code) pages = 1.333008 MB.
Stack = 0 bytes.
Library pages = 268.000 kB.